# Why don't rails tests give me useful error messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rake, functional-testing

I'm pretty new to Rails, and I'm trying to get some functional tests going on a rails application, and most of my tests are throwing errors. Something's set up wrong, I don't know what yet, trying to figure it out. But the testing output is seriously not helping me at all. Here's what my test output looks like (somewhat truncated):

```
Started

AttachmentsControllerTest:
     PASS should get index (0.29s)

ReaderControllerTest:
     PASS should get catalog (0.09s)
 should get volume (0.01s)

...

Finished in 0.411071 seconds.

6 tests, 5 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
rake aborted!
```

This is totally useless. Okay, there's an error in the volume test. What kind of error? Where's it being thrown? I don't know, and it won't tell me. The only way this could be less useful is if it just said "one or more of your tests has a failure and/or an error". This has to be a stupid newbie question, but how can I get some meaningful information out of the errors that get thrown?

Assume I know absolutely nothing about the testing built into Rails. Because I don't. I can't even find any documentation on reading the output, and the "give me a stack trace" command line argument just gives me the stack trace to the `exit 1` it uses to tell the OS there are failures, which is patently worthless.

**Edit:** I'm using 1.9.3, if it's relevant, and I'm running my tests with `rake test:functionals` (since there are currently no unit tests in there). Also, Neil asked about my rakefile, which reads as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env rake
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

Kidbooks::Application.load_tasks
```

And lib/tasks is empty.

Comment: Ruby test frameworks usually do give more information, and in case of exception a stack trace for the error. Could you show the Rakefile code you used to define the test task?

Comment: If you are using default rails test framework, you can add custom messages as an extra parameter to assert calls.

Comment: @NeilSlater: ...Rakefile code used to define the test task? I don't know what that means, and it doesn't sound familiar from the tutorials I read. I'll edit my rakefile into the question, but there's nothing about testing in there.

Comment: @fotanus: Good point. However, in this case there is an error, not a test failure, so OP should ideally be seeing a stack track from where it was raised.

Comment: @fotanus: Actually, I'm not getting the messages from failed assertions, either. `assert false, "This assertion always fails"` will cause a failure, but no message.

Comment: @user1618143: OK, sorry I should go one step back, how are you invoking your tests on the command line? I assumed a `rake` task (and it could still be so with those contents). Your comment about switching trace on using e.g. `--backtrace` implies that, too (and that flag is for tracing rake tasks, not tracing test errors, hence it does not do what you want).

Comment: @NeilSlater: `rake test:functionals`. What other options are there?

Comment: No other rake-specific options. There may be other ways to get control in from the command line, a quick Google suggests `rake test:functionals TESTOPTS="-v"` *might* help (this syntax sets environment that can be picked up by specific rake tasks), but although I am familiar with some Ruby test frameworks, the behaviour here I am less experienced with. Still we've identified some of the test setup, so I hope someone else can use that knowledge to help you further.